# Handle large number of http requests in react-redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need some help with my react-redux app project. I have some huge data which I split into small files, user has the option to select start and end time range. When the user press "Fetch data" button, I create http request promise object and push it into array and then wait for all the requests to finish with Promise.all(). It works well with small time range but if the user select big time range then I can see the lag in application. I have seen more than 50 HTTP requests in chrome developer tools. I was wondering what is the best way to handle large number of requests in react-redux application?

Comment: In range you request each element as a http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background info: Browsers limit concurrent requests. For example, Chrome has a limit of 6 connections per host name, and a max of 10 connections.

```
// Redux actions:
import axios from 'axios';

const LIMIT = 6;

const populateQueue = (requestConfigs) => ({ type: 'POPULATE_QUEUE', payload: requestConfigs });
const popRequest = () => ({ type: 'POP_REQUEST' });

export const initializeQueue = (requestConfigs) => (dispatch) => {
  // Grab as many request as we allow to run concurrently
  const initialRequests = requestConfigs.slice(0, LIMIT);

  // Put the rest in a queue
  const remainingRequests = requestConfigs.slice(LIMIT, requestConfigs.length);
  dispatch(populateQueue(remainingRequests));

  // Start the first batch. When one of requests finishes,
  // it will pop the next from the queue and start it.
  initialRequests.forEach((requestConfig) => dispatch(startRequest(requestConfig)));
};

const startRequest = (requestConfig) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    await axios(requestConfig);
    // process response here
  } catch(error) {
    // error handling
  } finally {
    const { queue } = getState().queuedRequests;
    if (queue.length) {
      // Queue not empty yet, start the next request
      const next = queue[0];
      dispatch(popRequest());
      dispatch(startRequest(next));
    }
  }
};

// Reducer:
const initialState = {
  queue: []
};

const queuedRequestReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'POPULATE_QUEUE') {
    return { queue: action.payload };
  } else if (action.type === 'POP_REQUEST') {
    return { queue: state.queue.slice(1, state.queue.length) };
  }

  return state;
};

export default queuedRequestReducer;

// In the React component this would be triggered with:
<button onClick={() => initializeQueue(requestConfigs)}>fetch a lot of data</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to implement this.

Comment: @MuhammadAwais I implemented what I had in mind and added code. It actually works without any counter, only one constant for the concurrency limit is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for...of` syntax for async requests. `Promise.all` runs all promises simultaneously. With `for..of` syntax, you will be executing request one by one.

For example

```js
const reqConfigs = [...] // array of request configs. 

for (const conf of reqConfigs) {
    const res = await fetchMyData(conf);
    // handle response...
}
```

UPD:

Split requests into buckets. Example.

```js
// generate request batches somehow. 
const reqConfigs = [...] // request batches configs. 

const fetchBatch = async (conf) => {
   const promises = ... //generate 10 promises
   const batchRes = await Promise.all(promises)
   return batchRes;
}

let allResults = [];

for (const conf of reqConfigs) {
    const batch = await fetchBatch(conf);
    // handle response...
    // Update progress bar... etc. 
    allResults.push(...batch)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I think I didn't explain my question clear enough. Handling promises simultaneously is not the problem, I just wanted to know it there is a better way to handle these simultaneously requests if the number of requests exceeds some threshold, like should I split them in multiple parts and handle one at a time. For example if I have to make 20 requests, Should I handle all simultaneously or 10 requests at a time?

Comment: If I do for...of syntax then it takes more than 30 seconds to load all the data if the duration is big. If I do simultaneously then app UI stuck for 2-3 secs but requests take about 5-8 secs.

Comment: You probably need to split all requests into buckets, for example 10 request per bucket. For each bucket use `Promise.all`, and iterate through buckets using `for..of`. I'll update the answer to demonstrate the concept. Also, as @kiran suggested, it is probably better to delegate this task to the server, and make only one request from client.

Comment: The downside of this is that you're waiting for the entire bucket of 10 requests to finish, but if some of them have already finished, you could already start with request from the next bucket.

Answer (score -2):

make the server side endpoint as it take the range in http header which is sent from react, give all the results in a single request. which will reduce you number of request, make your application better intuitive.

Comment: This just moves the queueing logic, which is needed to solve this, to the server. And it adds overhead because you need to aggregate data first on the server and then pack it up for the client to receive. Also you could run into timeouts if you wait for one big response for too long.